# Installing Windows 10 fresh copy over existing windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've windows 10 installed on my laptop, I'd installed a free edition with a product key available. Due to migration of many software from windows 7 to windows 10, my machine is not working as expected, many software are not running properly and performance is not up to.

I want to install a fresh copy of windows 10, wiping out everything.

I tried the inbuilt option to install (Recovery -> Reset this PC), however this didn't help, it stopped giving some strange errors.

What is the best approach to do this, retaining the license/product key?

Comment: Please include those "Strange errors", if possible, which might articulate the question to be understandable and problem can be detected based on those things

Comment: Boot to installation environment.  Delete all partitions, install Windows 10, Windows 10 will automatically activate. When asked for a product key skip that step. I have numerous other answers that go into more detail on the activation process of Windows 10. Here is one: https://superuser.com/questions/1258991/installing-windows-10-same-product-key-on-a-separate-drive-in-case-primary-dri/1259025#1259025